# Screen Sizes with res-long-hdpi

Tags: java, android, screen-size

I went through an online splash generator  and got :

```
res-long-land-xhdpi
res-long-port-xhdpi
res-long-land-xxhdpi
res-long-port-xxhdpi
res-notlong-land-xhdpi
res-notlong-port-xhdpi
res-notlong-land-xxhdpi
res-notlong-port-xxhdpi
```

from it. What are these used for?
Why should we use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android we have two types of orientation one is **Landscape** and other is **portrait** and we already know that they are different screen sizes like ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi so each and every screen and each orientation they are giving files to work your app in all android screen sizes perfectly.

Comment: Where should I place these folders? and will the app take these as drawables or take the drawabale folder images?

Comment: You should place these folders inside your resource folder in your project.

Comment: can you give me the pathway. as in. res>android>images>res-long-hdpi or res>res-long-hdpi

Comment: [link](http://apcmag.com/working-with-layouts-and-orientation-changes.htm)**http://apcmag.com/working-with-layouts-and-orientation-changes.htm**

Comment: Can I get to know the exact place to put it. or can you tell me a solution for the splash screen issue..

Answer (score 0):

You'll develop an app which supports screens with different resolution and hence you'll have a folder in you project for different density pixel images.

Long represents larger aspect ratio .
Not long represents standard aspect ratio.

For more info follow the below link..  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html